# Dereferencing an int pointer vs char pointer

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, dereference, string-literals

Assume this code in C:

```
int a = 5;
int *b = &a;
*b = 6;
```

Notice that `b` had to be dereferenced using `*` to have a value reassigned.

However, the same doesn't go with a char pointer (a String):

```
char *name = "test";
name = "test2";
```

`name` did not have to be dereferenced. Why is that?

Comment: When you de-reference a pointer, you reference the object that the pointer points to. So in the above assignment, you assign 6 to the variable `a`, not the pointer `b`.

Comment: Because the value of `name` isn't a `char`, but a `char*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
int a = 5;
int *b = &a;
*b = 6;
```

the last assignment stores the integer constant to the object pointed to by the pointer `b`. That is the value of the object `a` is changed not the value (address) stored in the pointer `b`.

In this code snippet

```
char *name = "test";
name = "test2";
```

the value of the pointer itself is changed not the object pointed to by the pointer. So at first the pointer name pointed to the first character of the string literal "test" and then it is reassigned to point to the first character of the string literal "test2".

It is the similar to the following code

```
int a = 5;
int *b = &a;

int a2 = 6;
b = &a2;
```

If you want to change an object pointed to by a pointer of the type `char *` you could write

```
char s[] = "test";
char *name = s;
*name = 'T';
```

In this case the array `s` will have "Test".

Pay attention that you may not change a string literal. That is if instead of the array s you will write

```
char *s = "test";
char *name = s;
*name = 'T';
```

then the code will have undefined behavior.

Also bear in mind that in this declaration

```
char *s = "test";
```

the string literal having the type `char[5]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `"test2"` is already `char[6]` (which in turn decays to `char*`). There's simply no need to use address-of on the rvalue, or dereference the lvalue to do the assignment for the types to work out.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that?

Because the two examples you show are not the same.

The were the same if you did:

```
/* your 1st example: */
int a = 5;
int *b = &a; /* b is a pointer to a what a is. */
*b = 6;
```

`a` equals `6` now.

```
/* your second example adjusted: */
char *a = "test";
char **b = &a; /* b is a pointer to a what a is. */
*b = "test2";
```

`a` points to `"test2"` now.